# Existence or evaluation of$\int^{+\infty}_{0}\frac{\log(x)}{1 + x\log^{2}(x)}dx$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Determine if the following integral exists and is finite:

$$\int^{+\infty}_{0}\dfrac{\log(x)}{1 + x\log^{2}(x)}dx$$

So, usually to determine if an improper integral exists and is finite you would have to determine if the limit exists and is finite:

$$\lim_{b\to +\infty}\int^{b}_{a}\dfrac{\log(x)}{1 + x\log^{2}(x)}dx$$

But that would require me to calculate the primitive of the function, and it doesn't look appealing.
When reading the calculus book made by my professor, I found a theorem that stated that for improper integrals of the type $[a, b[$ if $f(x)\ge 0$ in that interval, then the integral existed.

Now: $\dfrac{\log(x)}{1 + x\log^{2}(x)} \ge 0 $ only when $x \ge 1$, which is only a subset of the interval. Also in zero we have a divergence for log(x).

So my question is: does the theorem I mentioned above apply in this case, and if it does, why does it apply (considering the problems I've mentioned).

If it doesn't apply, what's the best course of action to find the primitive of the function?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The integral doesn't have a primitive in terms of elementary function. Yet it has a numerical result which is $12.31474776718283(...)$

Comment: Sorry, but your "theorem" is not true.  $f(x)= \frac{1}{1- x}$ is positive in $[0, 1)$ but $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1- x}$ does not exist.  Weren't  there other conditions on f?

Comment: Often people use the term 'limit exists' to refer to the fact that either the limit converges or it diverges either to $+\infty$ or to $-\infty$. So using this statement, an integral of any non-negative function always exists, but this does not exclude the possibility that the integral is infinite.

Comment: @HenryTuring so make prove by computer:)))). Somebody ask you help then you say the computer says.... hahaha. Note that computers are made by humans not aliens.

Comment: I am not getting how can you define$\ log^2 (x) $in [0,1]  as log cant have negative argument.

Comment: So, what I'm gathering by looking at the answers is that in cases where finding the primitive creates problems, I should try to find the answer by chains of inequalities and comparisons with other functions of known properties in that interval, right?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar yes. as you wrote x takes values in [0, 1] so the argument of the log is always positive. Whatever you get gets squared. so for example $log^{2}(x)$ with $ x = \dfrac{1}{2}$ would be equal to $(log(\dfrac{1}{2}))^{2} = (-0.301...)^{2} = 0.0906...$

Comment: Wait a sec $\log (x^2)\neq \log^2 (x)=\log (log (x)) $

Comment: @ArchisWelankar $\log^2 x$ is commonly used to denote either of $(\log x)^2$ and $\log \log x$. Here, the first interpretation is used.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar sorry I didn't know about $log(log(x))$ notation. In this case as Daniel said, it means $(logx)^{2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\in (0,1)$ we have $\log x\le 0$  and  $1\le 1+x\log^2(x)$ we get

$$\log(x) \le \frac{\log(x)}{1+x\log^2(x)}\le 0$$

Then this yields, 
$$-1 =[x\log x-x]_0^1= \int^{1}_{0}\log(x)dx\le\color{red}{\int^{1}_{0}\dfrac{\log(x)}{1 + x\log^{2}(x)}dx}\le 0$$

We have, $$\color{blue}{\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\log x\log x}{1+x\log^2( x)}=1 }$$ 
Therefore there exists $c>1$ such that for every $x>c$ we have,

$$\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{ x\log(x)}\le \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\log x\log x}{1+x\log^2( x)}\le \frac{3}{2}\dfrac{1}{ x\log(x)}}  $$

Then, use the [Bertrand Criteria](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand) to  see that 
$$\int^{+\infty}_{c}\dfrac{\log(x)}{1 + x\log^{2}(x)}dx\ge \frac{1}{2}\int^{+\infty}_{c}\dfrac{1}{ x\log^{}(x)}dx =\infty$$

diverges.

Now For $x\in(1,c)$ it converges as the integrand is continuous on $[1,c].$

Then your integral diverges since
$$\int^{+\infty}_{0}\dfrac{\log(x)}{1 + x\log^{2}(x)}dx =\int^{+\infty}_{c}\dfrac{\log(x)}{1 + x\log^{2}(x)}dx+\int^{c}_{1}\dfrac{\log(x)}{1 + x\log^{2}(x)}dx+\int^{1}_{0}\dfrac{\log(x)}{1 + x\log^{2}(x)}dx =\infty$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x\log^2 x}\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{t}{e^{-t}+ t^2}\,dt $$
is blatantly divergent since for any $M>0$
$$ \int_{0}^{M}\frac{t}{e^{-t}+t^2}\,dt\geq \int_{0}^{M}\frac{t}{1+t^2}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\log(M^2+1).$$

Comment: Please note that the question was about $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x\log^2 x}\,dx$$

Comment: @gimusi: whoops, misread, sorry. Now fixing.